# change the exit status of a C/C++ program during atexit callback

Tags: c++, exit, exit-code, atexit

I'm looking for a way to change the exit status of a C/C++ program during an atexit callback sequence.

I'm develping some C++ code that registers a book keeping function with atexit. If the program terminates as a result of an exit() call, this book keeping function prints a message if the data was left in an incomplete state. If this is the case, I want to make sure that the exit status of the program is nonzero. This is probably going to be true anyway, but it's also possible to call exit(0).

One solution is to call exit(-1) within the book keeping function that I've registered with atexit. This seems to work, but I *think* it's also undefined behavior. Does anyone know if this is correct? It's also unclear if this would terminate the atexit callback chain, which would be bad if there's another critical function registered with atexit.

Comment: If you are "..develping[sic] some C++ code..." why did you use the C tag?  Are you mixing languages?  C++ and C are different language; C++ has exceptions and the `throw` and `catch` keywords.  The C language doesn't.  FYI, there is no C/C++ language.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Returning normally from `main` includes an implicit `std::exit` call. Your inference that the program "should" have a nonzero return code because otherwise `exit` wouldn't have been called is not well-founded.

Comment: "This seems to work, but I think it's also undefined behavior. Does anyone know if this is correct?" -- I'm not sure about ISO C++, but in ISO C, according to [§7.22.4.4 ¶2 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4p2), calling `exit` more than once will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Re: `exit(-1)`: there are three portable exit codes: `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `0`. `0` is equivalent to `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is undefined behavior. I'm developing in C++, but I'm using a C library. On the C++ side, I've also registered the book keeping function with set_terminate, so that it will be called if the program exits because of an uncaught exception. That scenario is easier to handle because (as far as I'm aware) there's no possibility of a non-zero exit status.

Answer (score 4):

On POSIX systems, it is allowed to call `_exit` from within an `atexit` handler, however doing so means that any other `atexit` handler is not called.

Since `atexit` handlers are called in the reverse order of registration, have the first registered handler read a global variable and, if it's not set to some initial sentinel value, call `_exit` with that value.  Then any other handlers you register can modify that global if they want to override the exit value passed to `exit`.

For example:

```
#define EXIT_DEFAULT 0xffff
int exit_override = EXIT_DEFAULT;

void override_exit(void)
{
    if (exit_override != EXIT_DEFAULT) _exit(exit_override);
}

void handler1(void)
{
    if (some_error_condition) exit_override = 1;
}

int main()
{
    atexit(override_exit);
    atexit(handler1);
    // do something that might call exit
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I like the overall idea --- if we know for sure that the override_exit function is the first  registered with atexit, then it can do a final check on the exit status. However, it's possible for atexit to be called before main. I am registering my book keeping function before main, but I think the order of execution before main can't be controlled. Is there a way to ensure that the book keeping function is the first registered? Or, if  not, to rearrange the order? Actually, I recall a debate about what happens if we call atexit during an atexit call back.